# Hp Proliant dl380 g6: over temp error

Tags: hp-proliant

Hey guys I just received a dl380 from a auction and can’t get it to boot because after 30 seconds it shuts down and the over temp led is solid Amber on the front. I have removed everything but a processor in slot one and 2 sticks of ram. I reapplied thermal paste on the processor and reseated the cpu heat sink but yet I’m still getting the over heat error. I was wondering if you guys know a way for me to narrow down what’s wrong and hopefully fix it. Thank you in advanced and i can upload pictures and anything that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where you go back to the party or business that sold the system to you. Since this is an old server, *circa* 2009, HP won't be able to assist your directly. But go back to the source for repair or request a refund.

Comment: Yeah I tried but the nature of the auction was a bulk buy and this was one of the items. There is no refunds.